# Как лучше организовать раздачу фото с ватермаркой?

Tags: python, django

Стоит задача организовать раздачу фото с наложенной ватермаркой нескольким клиентам. Всего фото около 100 000 штук. Хочу спросить совета каким путем лучше пойти.

Первый вариант - генерировать эти фото заранее и раздавать как обычную статику через nginx, но это будет сжирать очень большое количество серверного места + эти фото нужно будет периодически перегенерировать.

Второй вариант - накладывать ватермарку прямо в момент обращения к фото с помощью бэкенда на Django. Для этого потребуется делать обращение к БД, чтобы понять по урлу какой логотип накладывать и организовать сам процесс наложения этого логотипа. То есть запрос будет выполняться дольше, и при выгрузке БД может получить 100 000 запросов подряд. Соответственно, это сильно увеличит нагрузку.

Посоветуйте какой способ выбрать, может быть я еще что-то не учел, или подскажите альтернативный способ решить эту задачу.

UPD. Маленькая уточнение - для каждого клиента нужно накладывать свой логотип. То есть с появлением каждого нового клиента, количество фото, которые нужно хранить, увеличивается на 100 000.

Comment: можно, например, попробовать с помощью той же pillow добавлять водяной знак на лету. https://pybit.es/pillow-intro.html

Comment: @strawdog ну pillow это да, чем же еще, но меня смущает скорее большое количество обращений к бэку. Боюсь, что вся эта uwsgi-конструкция может быть к такому не готова.